# How to get the value of each row and calculate for subtotal on page load

Tags: javascript, calculated-field

I have this script and related HTML that works fine and correctly calculates each row results and even in SubTotal and Total works fine.

The page loads budget data from a DB and often these data are already filled: I need to fill all calculated fields for each row on page load and to update it if changed.

I have already tried in all ways I know, but no one is working: I always need to mouseover a row or keyup on each row.

Here the code of Javascript

```
<script>
        $(document).on('pageshow load keyup mouseover change', '.topbar, .row-unitprice, .row-qty, .row-night, .item-row, .conteggia', function(e) {

        var $row = $(this).closest("tr"); //this is the closest common root of the input elements    
        var night = parseFloat($row.find('input.row-night').val());
        if (night > 0) {
            night = night;
        } else {
            night = 1;
        }
        var qty = parseFloat($row.find('input.row-qty').val());
        var unitprice = parseFloat($row.find('input.row-unitprice').val());
        Itemamount = (night * qty * unitprice) || 0;
        SubTotal =

        $row.find('input.row-amount').val(Itemamount.toFixed(2));
        var total = 0,
            grand_total = 0;
        //loop thrugh trs
        $(".item-row").each(function() {
            //add total & tax
            total += $(this).find(".row-amount").val() != "" ? parseFloat($(this).find(".row-amount").val()) : 0
        })
        grand_total = ({{scheda.budgettot}} - parseFloat(total));
        //add result to inputs
        $("#subtotal").val(total.toFixed(2))
        $("#total").val(grand_total.toFixed(2))
        $("#subtotal1").val(total.toFixed(2))
        $("#total1").val(grand_total.toFixed(2))
        });
</script>
```

And this is the HTML

```
<table>
<form method="post" action="{{this.id_evento}}" name="budget_{{this.item}}" class="conteggia">
    <input type="hidden" name="item" value="{{item}}" />
    <tr class="item-row">
        <td><input type="text" name="campo" value="{{this.campo}}" class="form-control row-desc" rows="1" style="min-width:100% !important;" /></td>
        <td><input class="form-control tx-right row-night" id="desc" rows="1" name="n" value="{{this.notti}}" style="max-width:100px !important;" /></td>
        <td><input class="form-control tx-right row-qty" type="text" id="qty" name="q" value="{{this.quanti}}" style="max-width:100px !important;" /></td>
        <td><input class="form-control tx-right row-unitprice" type="text" id="unitprice" name="p" value="{{this.prezzo}}" style="max-width:100px !important;" /></td>
        <td style="text-align:right;"><input class="form-control tx-right row-amount" type="text" id="amount"name="prezzone" readonly="true" style="max-width:120px !important;float:right;" /></td>
        <td style="white-space:nowrap;text-align:center;">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-square btn-warning btn-xs" title="Update"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</form>
</table>
```

Thanks you all for sure support to a newbie in this

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are asking about this right?

*I need to fill all calculated fields for each row on page load and to update it if changed.*

If you need to fill all calculated fields for each row on page load use the "load" event on JavaScript.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){ 
    // ...logic for filling all calculated fields
})
```

*and to update it if changed*

Put the value of what you what to change in a function and call it whenever the valued has changed, then set it to DOM.

You can also try to use an objects to update the DOM so whenever there is a change, you can update it.

```
 const sampleObj = {
       field1: "dog", // you can also assign function values here
       field2: "cat",
       field3: "bird",
}

element1.textContent = sampleObj.field1 // dog
element2.textContent = sampleObj.field2 // cat
element3.textContent = sampleObj.field3 // bird
```

// Let's say you update the value of an obj

```
sampleObj.field1 = "dinosaur"
sampleObj.field2 = "Stephen Curry"
sampleObj.field3 = 123456

element1.textContent = sampleObj.field1 // dinosaur
element2.textContent = sampleObj.field2 // Stephen Curry
element3.textContent = sampleObj.field3 // 123456
```

Comment: Thanks, but in this way it doesn't work yet.

As I change something in script, anything crashes!

Comment: Did you use objects for the calculated fields? If so, then you can first update the object then set it to DOM. Like this, const obj = {  a: 1 } then obj.a = 2 then el.textContent = obj.a

Comment: I don't know how many rows I'll get.
I cannot create a function for each row.

Comment: I'll edit my answer and try to suggest another way.

Comment: I can't know how many fields I will have on each loading.
That's why this way don't work in my case